# How to convert 1D tensor to regular javascript array?

Tags: tensorflow.js

How to convert 1D tensor to regular Javascript array in Tensorflow.js?

My 1D Tensor is like this:

```
Tensor [-0.0005436, -0.0021222, 0.0006213, 0.0014624, 0.0012601, 0.0007024, -0.0001113, -0.0011119, -0.0021328, -0.0031764]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`.dataSync()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#tf.Tensor.dataSync) to get the values of a tensor in a [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) and if you want a standard JS array you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which creates arrays out of array-like objects.

```js
const tensor = tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3]);
const values = tensor.dataSync();
const arr = Array.from(values);
console.log(values);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind using `.dataSync()` blocks the UI thread until the values are ready, which can cause performance issues. If you want to load the values asynchronously you can use [`.data()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#tf.Tensor.data), which returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) resolving to the TypedArray.

Answer (score 6):

To convert `tf.tensor` to plain js array there are `array()` and `arraySync()` methods.

e.g. `tf.tensor([1, 2, 5]).arraySync()`